# Job still running in buffer while :qa

Tags: terminal, quit, vim8

I'm using vim 8 with some plugins and shortcuts.

I set a shortcut for `:term` to open a terminal in vim:

```
nnoremap <F5> :wa<CR> \| :term<CR>
command Q qa
```

So when I type `F5`, a terminal will popup.

However, when I try to type `:Q` to close all of windows and quit vim, I get an error:

```
E947: Job still running in buffer "!/bin/bash"
```

So, I have to type `<C-d>` to close the terminal first, then `:Q` could work as expected.

I want to append some command for my `command Q qa | ???` but I don't know how.

It seems that `<C-w><C-c>` can close the terminal, but what if I opened two or three terminals? What I need is to make my command `Q` to close all of windows and quit vim immediately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Running process in a terminal buffer is treated mostly the same way as "an unsaved file". So you can do `:qa!` or `:set confirm` etc.etc. Well, anything to allow exit from Vim with buffers unsaved. But, of course, that will modify Vim's behaviour with respect to all buffers, not only terminals.

So if you only want to allow silent terminal closing, you should provide an extra option: `:term ++kill=term`. This instructs Vim to send `SIGTERM` to the running process if the terminal buffer needs to be closed.

Comment: Thanks! Any way to set this as a default option in vimrc?

Comment: @ShammelLee No, just press ctrl-w ctrl-c if you need to kill job.